# IIS Express application pool versions

Tags: .net, iis-express

I have a Windows 2003 server running IIS Express 7.5 with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 installed. The sites on the server had been using a version 2.0 app pool for quite some time. We want to use version 4.0 app pools. As a proof of concept I converted a project to .NET 4.0 and began hosting that in IIS Express. This is the sites section from my applicationhost.config file:

```
<sites>
    <site name="ShopServer80" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        .
        .
        .
        <application path="/Old2.0Application">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\WhereMyProjectLives"/>
        </application>
        .
        .
        .
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" enabled="false" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs"/>
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024"/>
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool"/>
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true"/>
</sites>
```

I want to just take the one application listed and use the `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` and have all of the others still use `Clr2IntegrationAppPool`, so I added the attribute `applicationPool`:

```
<application path="/New4.0Application" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\WhereMyProjectLives"/>
</application>
```

At this point, I am receiving the `BadImageFormatException`: **Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.**. Shouldn't that issue be resolved now that I'm specifying the `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` app pool for the application? The loaded runtime should be 4.0, right?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: IIS Express 7.5 is 32 bit only, so you might not use it to load a web app that requires 64 bit components.